# Is there anyway to aggregate multiple api end points to single swagger document

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm trying to aggregate multiple API endpoints to single swagger document. using [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) i couldn't find any sample code to approach

[image]

Even though added as multiple api documents all the requests should go through Gateway proxy service.

Any idea ?

Comment: I am actually working on a project that does just what you asking about.  I cannot make it public yet as it is proprietary code.  However I can lead you in the right direction with regard to the approach I took: I use a blank template spec file, then with appsettings in my application I set various info fields in the spec, then move on to combining "path" and "components" elements of the various json files that I pull via URLs of our apis.  Lastly you may need further massaging of combined spec if you're using a gateway, for instance server URLs and endpoint prefixes.